# Sprite inside a CONTAINER (which is inside a GROUP) is not visible

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I need to bounce a lot of tennis balls on screen. Each ball has a label text at it's centre. Since there can be a lot of balls, I'm using bitMap text for adding labels on the ball.

The approach I've followed till now to achieve this is as follows:

```
// Created a GROUP that will hold multiple balls
class Balls extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group {
  constructor(scene) {
    super(scene.physics.world, scene);

    // Keep adding'Ball' to the group here
    scene.time.addEvent({
      delay: 2000,
      loop: true,
      callback: () => {
        const ball = new Ball(scene);
        this.add(ball);
      },
    });
  }
  // do some other stuff
}

// Created a CONTAINER that will hold BALL SPRITE with BITMAP TEXT
class Ball extends Phaser.GameObjects.Container {
  constructor(scene) {
    super(scene, 0, 0);

    const ball = scene.physics.add.sprite(0, 0, 'myBall');
    const label = scene.add.bitmapText(0, 0, 'fontName', 'label text');

    this.add(ball);
    this.add(label);

    // Enabling physics on container
    scene.physics.world.enable(this);

    // Moving/Bouncing balls around the screen
    this.body.setVelocity(50, 50).setBounce(1).setCollideWorldBounds(true);
  }
  // do some other stuff
}
```

Now the problem is that the balls are **NOT VISIBLE** on screen however they are present and bouncing well on the screen (can see green outline around container after turning `debug: true`).

All I need to do is bounce some tennis balls around the screen with a label text on it's centre (need to update it quite often).

Comment: Can you try `this.scene.add.existing(this);` after super call. Otherwise, could you include more code that might show how you are adding this container to the scene.

Comment: @HarryScheuerle I read somewhere that adding a BODY inside an existing body like Container inside a group won't work. I'm not sure how much correct is this statement but then I changed the whole approach. I'm not using a container anymore but only groups.
And I was NOT ADDING THE CONTAINER directly into the scene. In class `Balls`, I have a timer that includes the container in a group. And then in 'create fn' of the scene, I was injecting the group in the scene.